# EF 4.1 Code First - Determine What Properties Have Changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, change-tracking

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First. Is there a built-in way to get a list of what properties have changed since the entity was loaded from the database? I know code first detects that an object was changed, but is there a way to get exactly what properties have changed?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For scalar and complex properties you can use the following to extract the changed property names of an entity `myEntity`:

```
var entry = context.Entry(myEntity);
var namesOfChangedProperties = entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames
    .Where(p => entry.Property(p).IsModified);
```

A few things to note here:

- `CurrentValues.PropertyNames` only contains scalar and complex properties, not navigation properties.
- Complex properties means: Only the name of the complex property which is declared on the entity, not the actual individual properties of the complex type itself, for example: If you have this model...

  ```
  [ComplexType]
  public class Address
  {
      public string Country { get; set; }
      public string City { get; set; }
  }

  public class Person
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public Address Address { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  ... then, if `myEntity` is a `Person`, `CurrentValues.PropertyNames` would contain "**Id**", "**Name**" and "**Address**" but not "**Address.Country**" or "**Address.City**" (nor "**Country**" or "**City**").
- If a complex property is marked as modified (`.IsModified` in the code above is `true`) then this means that either the reference (`Person.Address` in the example above) has changed, no matter if actually the property values (`Country` and `City`) inside of the complex type have changed or not. Or that any of the properties of the complex type has changed (`Country` or `City` has changed). I believe it's not possible to find out which one, because EF always sends an UPDATE command for *all* complex type properties to the database, even if only one property has changed and the other remained unchanged. I would conclude from this that EF doesn't track changes of individual complex type properties.

Comment: great, works for me with Entity framework 6 as well!